# Netty AbstractChannel.isWritable has logic error?

Tags: netty

the code:

```
return (getInterestOps() & OP_WRITE) == 0;
```

so when the `interestops == 5(OP_READ_WRITE)`,  `channel.isWritable()==false`, this is confusing, I think is should be true.

Answer (score 0):

No.  `OP_WRITE` flag means 'the channel is not writable at the moment (i.e. buffer full) and thus the channel is interested in the changes in its write buffer status.'  Therefore, it's correct.